# Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file

Tags: spring

I used framework Spring  and am now using it for a little sample project. However I keep having an error in my spring.xml configuration file :

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - <bean class="com.dao.StudentDaoImpl" id="stdDaoBean" />
    - Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for 
     com.dao.StudentDaoImpl
```

my code spring is:

```
   <bean class="com.dao.StudentDaoImpl" id="stdDaoBean" />
    <bean class="com.service.StudentServiceImpl" id="stdServiceBean">
        <property name="studentDao" ref="stdDaoBean"></property>
    </bean>
```

StudentDao the class exists and I have the spring jar, as well; I do not know where the probelm is, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `com.dao.StudentDaoImpl` class is in reality in some other package than `com.dao`. Or the class name is different, you said that `StudentDao the class exists` but you used `StudentDaoImpl` name in `spring.xml`. So check the package and class names.

Comment: si si the class studentDaoImpl exist too

Comment: But is it in `com.dao` package? And to make sure, it should be named `StudentDaoImpl` because class name is case sensitive.

Comment: all is not well written spelling

Comment: and the classe StudentDaoImpl exist in package com.dao